# regex_replace value that starts with char, followed by integers BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I have a table in BigQuery that I need to clean up. In column `content_column` I have values like:

```
content_column
/a68786776
/g263647
/g47664
/galleries
/music
```

I want to replace all values that start with `/g` followed by any number of integers to a string `gallery`. The desired output is:

```
content_column
/a68786776
gallery
gallery
/galleries
/music
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(content_column,r'\/(\w+\d+)\/', "gallery") as content_column
FROM `my_table`
```

This works but it also converts `/a68786776` to `gallery`. I tried to replace `(\w+\d+)` to `(\^g\d+)` but that didn't convert anything to gallery.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Why not `\/g\d+` or `^\/g\d+`

Comment: as in `r'\/(\/g\d+)\/'` ?

Comment: If you want to replace the whole match with "gallery" you don't need the capture group. I think `r'\/g\d+'` might work.

Comment: `r'\/g\d+` works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use `r'/g\d+'`, no need to escape `/`, you are not defining the regex with a regex literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select if(
    regexp_contains(content_column,r'^/g\d+'), 
    'gallery', 
    content_column
  ) as content_column
from `my_table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the full match with `gallery` you don't need a capture group in the pattern.

- This pattern `\w+\d+` matches 1+ word chars and 1+ digits, which is a minimum of 2 characters and does not specify a `g` char
- This pattern `\^g\d+` matches `^g` and 1+ digits.

Instead you can match `/` and 1 or more digits:

```
r'/g\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tra2nr/1)

Or match from the start of the string using an anchor `^` (wihout the backslash) with a multiline flag:

```
(?m)^/g\d+
```